# Iterate over Each Argument Between && or || in an Expressions<Func<T,Bool>> Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, generics, lambda, expression, func

I want a method that operates similarly to following LINQ-to-SQL `Where` method.

```
 db.Where(r => r.Age == 42 && r.Name = "Joe");
```

I would like to take an implementation of:

```
Something something = Get<Something>()
    .FilterBy(x => x.PropOne == 123 && x.PropTwo == 456);
```

and using a method like below; have the ability to access the **Left.Name**, **Operator** and **Right.Value** of each expression argument to perform work.

```
public static T FilterBy<T>(this T something, Expression<Func<T, object>> e)
{
    // do work here
}
```

So far I can parse single condition like `x => x.PropOne == 123` without the use of && or || using the below.

```
public static T FilterBy<T>(this T something, Expression<Func<T, object>> e)
{
    BinaryExpression binaryExpression = 
        (BinaryExpression)((UnaryExpression)e.Body).Operand;

    string left = ((MemberExpression)binaryExpression.Left).Member.Name;
    string right = binaryExpression
        .Right.GetType().GetProperty("Value")
        .GetValue(binaryExpression.Right).ToString();

    ExpressionType @operator = binaryExpression.NodeType;
    return (T)Convert.ChangeType(something, typeof(T));
}
```

How can I access the each of the expression arguments when parts of expression combined with `&&` or `||`?

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I would like to know how I can access each of the expression arguments from the method (using the example implementation).

Comment: expression arguments? Sorry, still don't get it. Maybe someone else will have more luck.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I would like to access `x.PropOne == 123` and `x.PropTwo == 456` each individually from inside `FilterBy<T>()`.  Sorry if it is still not clear.  I want a method that operates similarly to LINQ's Where method.

Comment: @SBPhoenix - please check if my edit matches your question - tried to inline your comments.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Thank you for helping me clarify.

Comment: FYI:  Not sure if you considered this but, if `Get<Something>` returns a type that implements `IEnumerable<>` then you can use IEnumerable's .Where method.  Make sure you have your LINQ using statement and call `Something something = Get<Something>()
    .Where(x => x.PropOne == 123 && x.PropTwo == 456);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Example Code

Here is an example of how to get the `&&`:

```
public static class FilterExtension
{
    public class Condition
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Value { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
    }

    public static T FilterBy<T>(this T something, Expression<Func<T, object>> e)
    {
        var conditions = new List<Condition>();
        BinaryExpression binaryExpression =
       (BinaryExpression)((UnaryExpression)e.Body).Operand;
        CheckConditions(conditions, binaryExpression);
        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(test, typeof(T));
    }

    private static void CheckConditions(List<Condition> conditions, BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
    {
        if (binaryExpression.NodeType == ExpressionType.AndAlso)
        {
            CheckConditions(conditions, binaryExpression.Left as BinaryExpression);
            CheckConditions(conditions, binaryExpression.Right as BinaryExpression);
        }
        else
        {
            conditions.Add(GetCondition(binaryExpression));
        }
    }

    private static Condition GetCondition(BinaryExpression binaryExpression)
    {
        var condition = new Condition();
        condition.Name = ((MemberExpression)binaryExpression.Left).Member.Name;
        condition.Value = binaryExpression
            .Right.GetType().GetProperty("Value")
            .GetValue(binaryExpression.Right, null).ToString();
        condition.Operator = binaryExpression.NodeType.ToString();
        return condition;
    }
}
```

Obviously the code for `&&` is not complete; you should get an idea.

Also, I noticed that you pass in an object of type `T`. If this were to work like Linq-To-SQL where, it probably should be some kind of list or enumerable.

Example: 
`public static T FilterBy<T>(this List<T> something, Expression<Func<T, object>> e)`

## Considerations

Just as a note of caution, a lot of different expressions can be passed into this method that will compile but will break your method.

`Something something = Get<Something>().FilterBy(x => 123 == x.PropOne);`

`Something something = Get<Something>().FilterBy(x => x.Method() == 123);`

`Something something = Get<Something>().FilterBy(x => (x.PropOne == 123 || x.PropOne == 34) && x.PropTwo == 456 );`

Make sure to verify that the expression is the type that you are expecting it to be.

Comment: This certainly helps and thank you very much for your considerations and example. How would I go about iterating over each `&&`? Would I use a `foreach` loop and if so, do you happen to know an example of how?

Comment: I changed my example to show a basic implementation using recursion. I also made the assumption that you want to capture the values of the expressions, so I am storing them in a list. Does this seem to be what you were looking for?

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for except I seem to get a compile error with `CheckConditions(conditions, binaryExpression.Left)` and `CheckConditions(conditions, binaryExpression.Right)` stating that `CheckConditions` is an unknown method? Once again, I truly appreciate all of your help!

Comment: This is _EXACTLY_ what I needed and works like a charm! Thank you _SO_ much for your help. I've been racking my brain over this as I'm new to expressions in general.